# Transparent UIImage is not tranrperent in navBar

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I've created an white image with a white alpha on 0.2. However when i add it it does not seem to be transparent in the navigationBar. It is completely white. i did the same thing with tabBar, which worked fine. What am i doing wrong. this is in a viewControllers ViewDidLoad:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Navbar"), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One foolproof way of controlling the alpha value of a UIImage when using UIImageView is not an option is giving the image an initial alpha of 1, then adding this UIImage extension:

```
extension UIImage{

func alpha(value:CGFloat)->UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)

    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    let area = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height);

    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -area.size.height);
    CGContextSetAlpha(ctx, value);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, area, self.CGImage);

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
}
```

...then in ViewDidLoad:

```
let newNavBar = UIImage(named: "navBar")!.alpha(0.2)

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "newNavBar"), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```